# Is there a way to add something to the exception message in Cucumber After hook?

Tags: cucumber

This will output exception message:

```
After {|scenario| p scenario.exception.message}
```

I would like to just add some text there, something like this:

```
After {|scenario| scenario.exception.message << "extra data"}
```

But of course, that does not work.

Comment: I think you can get more detailed answer in [Cucumber discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!forum/cukes). I think they will ask you why you need this so you will be better to write it before they ask))

Comment: Thanks. I have asked at cucumber IRC channel, and posted link to this question there. I will update the question with more context and send the link to cucumber google group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the way to do it is to create custom Cucumber formatter. Something like this:

```
require 'cucumber/formatter/junit'

module Cucumber::Formatter
  class Custom < Junit
    def format_exception(exception)
      (["extra data"] + ["#{exception.message} (#{exception.class})"] + exception.backtrace).join("\n")
    end
  end
end
```

and then run features with the custom formatter:

```
$ cucumber --format Cucumber::Formatter::Custom --out reports
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write:

```
After do |scenario|
  p scenario.exception.message
end
```

and run Cucumber in console you will see that it prints it's own exception message to console before execution of After hook.

So, to my understanding, you can't change Cucumber's exception message as it's already printed to the output.

As a workaround you can raise your own exception:

```
After do |scenario|
  raise 'my message'
end
```

It will appear in Cucumber's output